# How to use the resource_owner grant within Microsoft365R

Tags: r, microsoft365r

I'm trying to implement an unattended script accessing files within OneDrive using Microsoft365R.
I've setup everything like in the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R) using the default app registration.

The interactive flow with **auth_type="device_code" works** without issues:

```
odb <- Microsoft365R::get_business_onedrive(auth_type="device_code")
```

But when trying **auth_type="resource_owner"** like shown in the docs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/scripted.html), I get the following **error**:

```
odb <- Microsoft365R::get_business_onedrive(tenant=tenant, app=app, username=user, password=getPass(), auth_type="resource_owner")
```

> Error in process_aad_response(res) :
> Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to obtain Azure Active Directory token. Message:
> AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.

My guess is, that the default app is missing some privileges to use the "resource_owner" flow.
Can someone point me to the right direction on how to get the resource_owner flow working?

*(Using Service Principles is not a solution for my setup, but I did also try it with a dedicated service account and it was not working either)*

Comment: Double-check that you have the correct username and password

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I used the correct username and password.